# Cannot import file from a package (Python)

Tags: python

I have this directory:

```
Project
└── functions
    ├── __init__.py
    └── b.py
└── a.py
```

b.py:

```
def hello():
    print('Hello World')
```

a.py:

```
import functions

functions.b.hello()
```

However, when I run a.py, it gives this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'functions' has no attribute 'b'
```

I have also tried this:

```
from functions import b
```

But then it just says that b isn't defined.

I understand that I could do this:

```
from functions import b
```

and then run the rest of my code, but I don't want to, because I'm planning on having a lot of other modules in functions. Is there any other way to get this to work?

Comment: What's the content of your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Nothing. I just left it blank

Comment: @BlazingLeaf12 then that's why it's failing. Just import it there. Anyway, it'll be good for us if you show your code, that's the way we can help you better. Questions need to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you want it blank then you'll have to do `from functions.b import hello`

Comment: Alright, I imported b, but it says this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'

Comment: Try `import functions.b` , U can import file itself. It works

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `__init.py__`.

`from functions import b`